# Data transfer between unbound components in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

There is a part of the page

```
<Header/>
<Switch>
<Route path={/componentOneURL} component={ComponentOne} />
<Route path={/componentTwoURL} component={ComponentTwo} />
</Switch>
<Footer/>
```

This is a conditional part of the apk here Header Footer and the element that is loaded when you switch to the corresponding rout
It is necessary to change the state of Header, depending on which element we switched to in Switch, for myself I derived 2 possible solutions to the problem:

1. hide Header in ComponentOne and ComponentTwo and there it is no longer a problem.
2. through Redux (I only teach the redux so I myself don’t know how to create one, but it’s possible to create one)

Both options seem to me crutches so maybe someone will tell me some simple option that I might have missed due to inexperience

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 options that you can use depending on your problem.

1. If you want to simply change the active class name of a link in your Header, you can use NavLink activeClassName:

`<NavLink to={"/componentOneURL"} activeClassName="active" className="link">componentOne</NavLink>`

2. If you need a more general case, you are sharing state between two child components. You can pass functions through the parent:

   `setHeaderState=(value)=>{
    this.setState({headerState:value});
   }`

   `<Header headerState={this.state.headerState}/>
   <Switch>
   <Route path={'/componentOneURL'} render={() => <ComponentOne setHeaderState={this.setHeaderState}/>} />
   <Route path={'/componentTwoURL'} render={() => <ComponentTwo setHeaderState={this.setHeaderState}/>} />
   </Switch>
   <Footer/>`